# Find the 4-digit code!

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

An agent has created a 4 digit code from the result of a maths equation involving all the digits 1-9. We know where the number 3 appears in the multiplication, but not any of the other 8 digits.

```
   ###  
 X  3#  
= ####
```

We require the 4 digit code from the equation. Can you find it?

Edit: the brute force solution is trivial - can you find another way?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is doable computerless without too much pain.

The sum of all the digits is 45, a multiple of 3. If the numbers are a,b,c then we know a+b+c=0 (mod 3) and ab=c, so a+b+ab=0 so (1+a)(1+b)=1 so {a,b} is either {0,0} or {1,1}, so **{a,b,c} is either {0,0,0} or {1,1,1} mod 3**.

The first number is being multiplied by at least 31 and giving an answer at most 9876, so it's at most floor(9876/30)<=320. Its first digit can't be 3 because we have a 3 elsewhere, so **the first number begins with 1 or 2**. (And then the final number begins with at least a 4.)

Now, **if a,b,c are all multiples of 3** (the first of our two cases from the first paragraph) then of course the product must actually be a multiple of 9; then a,b add up to a multiple of 9 and therefore they are either 0,0 or (in some order) 3,6 mod 9. *Is 0,0 possible?* The second number would need to be 36 and then we readily find that the first must have digits {1,8,9}, and neither 189 nor 198 works. *Is 3,6 possible?* That would require the second number to be 33, which it can't be. *Is 6,3 possible?* The other possibility is that the second number is 39, in which case the first must be 6 mod 9. That means digits {1,6,8} or {2,5,8} or {2,6,7}. We can quickly check all six cases and find that **186x39=7254 works** and the other five don't.

**Otherwise, all three of our numbers are 1 mod 3**. In particular the second is one of {31,34,37}. It can't actually be 31 because then the first and third numbers would have the same last digit. So **the second number is 34 or 37**.

OK, then what's the first? Its digits add up to 1 mod 3, and it begins with 1 or 2. So the options for digits mod 3 are: 100, 112, 121, 202, 211, 220. Here a 1 or 2 in the first digit means what it says; after that 0 means 6 or 9, 1 means one of {1,4,7}, and 2 means one of {2,5,8}. The number can't end in 5 because then the third number ends in 0, forbidden, or 5, duplicate. Neither can we use both 4 and 7, because we need one for the second number. So, taking a deep breath, we enumerate: "100" 169 196; "112" 142 148 172 178; "121" 124 154 184 127 157 187; "202" 268 298; "211" 214 217 241 271; "220" 256 259 286 289.

That's eminently checkable by hand; 14 of the 22 possibilities contain either a 4 or a 7, so we only have 30 multiplications to check. We can prune a little further (e.g., no point trying xx6 times 34 because there'll be a 4 at the end of the product; no point trying xx9 times 37 because there'll be a 3 at the end of the product) but frankly it's as easy just to check them all. And it turns out that **none of these works out**.

Therefore, the only solution is 186x39 = 7254.

Answer (score 3):

This was easy:

> 186*39=7254.

I have found this by computers. This is the unique solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you could've gotten the answer even without the hint of '3' right?

Comment: Specifying one digit is required to have uniqueness: see the triplets {a,b,a*b} in {{138, 42, 5796}, {157, 28, 4396}, {159, 48, 7632}, {186, 39, 7254}, {198, 27, 5346}, {297, 18, 5346}, {483, 12, 5796}}.

Comment: Ahh, to narrow it down to a single answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Forgot to specify no brute force solutions - see edit to puzzle!