# Guess the missing digits

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

Can you guess the missing digits in the following multiplication?

??? x 3? = ????

Digits from 1 to 9 appear exactly once each.

The goal is to solve it with as little calculation as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the 4-digit code!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43045/find-the-4-digit-code)

Answer (score 4):

> 186*39=7254

How to get the answer:

> Let's label the numbers from left to right as $a_1,...,a_8$. Note that $a_1$ is at most $3$ since the result of the product must be $3$ digits. Since $3$ is already used, $a_1=1$ or $2$. Let's first run with the assumption that $a_1=2$.

Hence,

> If $a_1=2$, since $256*34>8700$, $a_5=8$ or $a_5=9$. If $a_5=8$, then $a_3=4$ as $254*36>9000$ (It's obvious that $a_3, a_4\neq5$.) And, we know that $a_6>6$ from the same calculation. Via $3$ multiplications, we can see that $a_2\neq5\to a_2>5$. But, $34*267>9000$.

So,

> $a_5=9$.

Still being edited...

Comment: That was quick, curious to see how you proceeded. My solution still requires ~60 multiplications.

Comment: You may want to hide the method with a spoiler tag

Comment: I'm going to finish this later: have a class to attend. It's a bunch of casework as above.